# Unknown provider: 3Provider <- 3 using Angular Bootstrap uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

It's been a few weeks with this problem, I'm new to Angular so I hope is an easy fix.

I'm using Angular Bootstrap Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) and it's not working. this is my code.

On contentApp.js (with additional config options)

```
angular
    .module('contentApp', [
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.router',
        'satellizer',
        'angular-jwt',
        'angular.morris-chart'
    ])

// Additional Configuration...
```

On TransModalController.js

```
angular
    .module('contentApp')
    .controller('TransModalController', TransModalController)
    .controller('MICnewGroup', MICnewGroup)
    .controller('MICaddTransmitter', MICaddTransmitter);

function TransModalController($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log) {

    $scope.openModal = function (url) {

        var ModalInstanceController = "";

        if ('newGroup' == url) {
            url = "php/modal/newGroup.html";
            ModalInstanceController = 'MICnewGroup'

        } else if ('addTransmitter' == url) {
            url = "php/modal/addTransmitter.html";
            ModalInstanceController = 'MICaddTransmitter'
        };

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({             //<-- Line 26
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: url,
            controller: ModalInstanceController,
            size: 'sm',
            resolve: {
                user: $scope.sub
            }
        });
    };
}


// Controller for Modal Instance of New Group
function MICnewGroup($scope, $http, $state, $uibModalInstance, user) {
    $scope.newGroup = {
        'user': user,
        'name': ''
    }

    $scope.createGroup = function() {

        $http.post('api/user/'+$scope.sub+'/group', $scope.newGroup)
            .then(function(data) {
                $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams

                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }
        );
    }
}

// Controller for Modal Instance of Add Transmitter
function MICaddTransmitter($scope, $http, $state, $uibModalInstance, user) {
    $scope.newTransmitter = {
        'user': user,
        'code': ''
    }

    $scope.addTransmitter = function() {

        $http.put('api/transmitter/'+$scope.newTransmitter.code, $scope.newTransmitter)
            .then(function(data) {
                $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); //second parameter is for $stateParams

                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

All this works fine on my **localhost** (Mac), but when uploaded to my **Server** (Ubuntu) throws me this error

```
angular.js:12477Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 3Provider <- 3
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=3Provider%20%3C-%203
  at angular.js:68
  at angular.js:4289
  at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4437)
  at angular.js:4294
  at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4437)
  at ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:4056
  at Object.forEach (angular.js:350)
  at getResolvePromises (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:4052)
  at Object.$modal.open (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:4097)
  at Scope.TransModalController.$scope.openModal (TransModalController.js:26)
```

Angular is **v1.4.7**, ui.bootstrap is **v0.14.3**

Why it works on my **Localhost** but not on my **Server**?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely due to minification, see the 'A note on minification' section at this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Comment: Not using minification. Also, tried both link's solutions anyway; neither worked.

Comment: @fglaria Then why do your error messages reference ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js?  That is the minified version of the ui-bootstrap library.

Comment: My bad, I'm using Gulp and for this error changed the source file from the minified version to non-minified, but didn't change the output file, so it's named .min.js, but is not.